# MySQL: AES_ENCRYPT vs DES_ENCRYPT

Tags: mysql, encryption

This may have already been asked before but which is better, `AES_ENCRYPT` or `DES_ENCRYPT`? Also when would be the best time to use either one instead of creating hashes in PHP?

Comment: This question has indeed already been asked. Short answer: use AES.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Feel free to close this any time.